# Why don't these need to be defined here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, requirejs-define

I was looking at an API provided by Google and I needed to translate it to jQuery, so I did. In Google's code, Google defined the created elements, but it works without defining them in jQuery mobile. I'm new to programming, so I'm unsure about if this matters or not? The code works without errors on the console log, without defining.

Google:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(panoramioLayer, 'click', function(photo) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.innerHTML = photo.featureDetails.title + ': ' +
       photo.featureDetails.author;
    link.setAttribute('href', photo.featureDetails.url);
    li.appendChild(link);
});
```

jQuery:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(panoramioLayer, 'click', function(photo) {
    $(document.createElement("a")).html("photo.featureDetails.title + ': ' + photo.featureDetails.author");
    $("a").attr("href", photo.featureDetails.url);
    $("li").append("a");
});
```

Comment: Your jQuery won't work too well since you're setting **ALL** a tags and **ALL** li tags in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The correct conversion should be like this :-

```
google.maps.event.addListener(panoramioLayer, 'click', function(photo) {
    var anchor=$("<a/>").html(photo.featureDetails.title + ': ' + photo.featureDetails.author).attr("href", photo.featureDetails.url);
    $("<li/>").append(anchor);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(panoramioLayer, 'click', function(photo) 
{
    var $link = $(document.createElement("a")).html(photo.featureDetails.title + ': ' + photo.featureDetails.author);
    $link.attr("href", photo.featureDetails.url);
    $("<li/>").append($link);
});
```

You need to store the created link tag, so that you don't change ALL a tag's hrefs

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually having trouble with the panoramio in general actually. When I navigate (I'm using jQueryMobile) from the index to the map page I get an error saying:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PanoramioLayer' of undefined.

It has something to do with the following code that appears above the original code that I posted: 
 var panoramioLayer = new google.maps.panoramio.PanoramioLayer();
and below that is: 
panoramioLayer.setMap(map);

Comment: @snowhite I think that should be a new question then